# Non-INR transactions in India should have shipping/billing address outside India

Tags: reactjs, express, stripe-payments

I am using stripe for my payment for a personal project even though I am giving the currency as INR and providing an Indian address it is showing me the error Non-INR transactions in India should have shipping/billing address outside India.

usersCltr.payment = async (req, res) => {
const booking = req.body

```
const lineItems = [booking].map((ele) => ({
    price_data: {
        currency: 'inr',
        product_data: {
            name: ele.name
        },
        unit_amount: ele.price*100
    },
    quantity:1,
}))

const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    line_items:lineItems,
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: 'http://localhost:3000/payment/success',
    cancel_url: 'http://localhost:3000/payment/cancel',
    customer_email:'testuser2@gmail.com',
    billing_address_collection:'require',
    shipping_address_collection:{
        allowed_countries:['IN']
    }
})

res.json({id: session.id})
```

}

What should I do?

I have tried it with various version but still cannot fix it.

Comment: We can't validate your request given the limited information such as your Stripe account country and exact parameters received at Stripe's end. I'd recommend writing to Stripe Support https://support.stripe.com/contact with the request ID (req_xxx) of the error, so that they can check it for you.